# Determine when sent user to home if logged in correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Im developing a mobile app and i need to determine when user is logged in correctly to send into Home page, else user only see Login page.

My user.ts (Provider)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { api } from '../../config/url.api';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx"
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { AlertController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

// Plugin storage
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class User {

  user_id: string;
  user_firstname: string;

  constructor( public http: Http, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private platform: Platform, private storage: Storage ) {

    // Cargamos el storage con datos almacenados
    this.load_storage();

  }

  login_user( US_EMAIL: string, US_PASSWD: string ){

    let data = new URLSearchParams();

    data.append( "Usuario_app[US_EMAIL]", US_EMAIL );
    data.append( "Usuario_app[US_PASSWD]", US_PASSWD );

    let url = "/api" + "/usuario_app/acceso"; // Cambiame en los builds

    return this.http.post( url, data )
    .map( resp => {
      let data_resp = resp.json();
      console.log( data_resp );

      if( data_resp.ResponseError ) {

        // Si el JSON retorna error al enviar datos a la API, mostramos una alerta
        this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: "Error",
          message: data_resp.ResponseError,
          buttons: ["Aceptar"]
        }).present();

        console.log('Hubo un error al iniciar sesión');

      } else {
        // El JSON retornó sin errores
        this.user_id = data_resp.USUARIO.US_ID;
        this.user_firstname = data_resp.USUARIO.US_NOMBRE;

        // Almacenamos la ID del usuario
        this.save_storage();

        console.log('Sesión inciada con éxito, se guardó en el storage');
      }
    })
  }

  remove_user(){

    this.user_id = null;

    // guardar storage
    this.save_storage();

  }

  private save_storage(){

    if( this.platform.is("cordova") ){

      // En el dispositivo
      this.storage.set('user_id', this.user_id );

    } else {

      // En el Computador
      if( this.user_id ){
        localStorage.setItem("user_id",  this.user_id  );
        console.log('Guardé el user_id: ' + this.user_id);
      } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("user_id");

        console.log('Borré de tu local el usuario');
      }
    }
  }

  load_storage(){

    let promise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {

      if( this.platform.is("cordova") ){

        // dispositivo
        this.storage.ready()
        .then( () => {
          this.storage.get("user_id")
          .then( user_id => {
            if( user_id ) {
              this.user_id = user_id;
            }
            resolve();
          })
        })
      } else {
        // computadora
        if( localStorage.getItem("user_id") ){
          //Existe items en el localstorage
          this.user_id = localStorage.getItem("user_id");
          console.log('Cargué el user_id: ' + this.user_id);
        }
        resolve();
      }
    });

    return promise;
  }
}
```

Okay, so, when user is in Login Page, have two options

- Login Sucessfully -> Go Home
- Login Incorrect -> Try Again

I try some snippet but user goes to Home when the login is incorrect too

My login.ts (Page)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
// import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
// import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import * as sha1 from 'js-sha1';

import { User } from "../../providers/user/user";

import { HomePage } from '../../pages/home/home';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  US_EMAIL: string = "";
  US_PASSWD: string = "";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private user: User, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController ) {
    // console.log('Mensaje encriptado ' + sha1('Hola soy un mensaje encriptado'));
  }

  login(){

    // Envía la password encriptada en SHA1
    this.user.login_user( this.US_EMAIL, sha1(this.US_PASSWD) )
    .subscribe( () => {

      // Acá tendría que discriminar si enviar o no al usuario al home siempre cuando haya validado su inicio de sesión

      // console.log( 'Encripté tu contraseña: ' + sha1( this.US_PASSWD ));

    })
  }
}
```

In advance, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This type of functionality is often handled using a route guard. There is an authorization example here: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards